Issue floating div on each side of div while having center div take up the spaces between the two floating divs when it comes to width and height
I'm trying to float div on each side of div in center containing a menu that is vertically and horizontally centered to the divs on each side. For instance the center div (menu container) takes up the space between the two floated divs vertically and horizontally.
Here is my code so far..
CSS
#HeaderContainer
{
    overflow: hidden
}

#Logo1Container
{
    Width: 200px;
    Height: auto;
    Float: left;
}

#Logo2Container
{
    Width: 200px;
    Height: auto;
    Float: right;
}

#MenuContainer
{
    Width: auto;
    Height: auto;
    Display: flex;
    Justify-content: center;
    Text-align: center;
}


ASP.Net Masterpage
<div id="HeaderContainer">
    <div id="#Logo1Container">
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Media/Corp Logo Sample                                                   Test.jpg" Width="200px"/>
    </div>
    <div id="#Logo2Container" >
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Media/Corp Logo Sample Test.jpg" Width="200px"/>
    </div>
    <div id="MenuContainer">
        <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1" Orientation="Horizontal" StaticDisplayLevels="2"></asp:Menu>
        <asp:SiteMapDataSource runat="server" ID="SiteMapDataSource1"></asp:SiteMapDataSource>
    </div>

</div>



I was able to get it to center horizontally but haven't gotten it to center vertically... Any suggestions?
